# Mesh is Not Moving with the Armature

Tags: armature, bones

I imported an OBJ file to use as a mesh and followed the most-viewed YouTube videos on creating bones for models, as well as the instructions found in this [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5151/model-wont-follow-its-armature-in-pose-mode?newreg=3af7873136514f66a0f70dc97a8f1674) and I believe I'm doing everything correctly. Yet, the mesh is still not moving with the armature. I also looked at similar questions when writing this, such as [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100579/mesh-not-moving-with-armature) and [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137451/mesh-and-armature-not-connected), but these did not appear to solve my problem either (or I did not understand how to apply the answers correctly).

To be exact about the process I used to get where I currently am with the model, I created bones for each of the mesh's arms and extended them, then connected them both to a parent bone in the middle of the mesh before making the armature the parent of the mesh and deforming the armature with automatic weights.

[image: screenshot of the model]

Here is a [link to the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/136gsD7h24tjkry5eCWYbnlIcaCUaLaFw/view?usp=sharing). Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get the mesh to move with the bones when the bones are reposed?

Comment: Link give access denied.  Please upload to blend-exchange instead. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @MartyFouts I'm getting an internal error when uploading to blend-exchange with a 413 error code (size of file is too large). I made the link public, sorry about that!

Comment: This is too much vertex density, leading to bone heat failure (look for error messages on autoweights.)  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones.  Even if you were to get this weighted, like manually, it would be impractical to pose.  You need to retopo the model to something lower poly.

Comment: And, btw, the reason the file is too big is 1) too many vertices and 2) uncompressed file.  Open a sidebar in file save dialog to see sidebar with options, including "compress" option.

Comment: @Nathan sounds like a decent answer to be posted as such, right? :o

Comment: @L0Lock it's approximately the 9000th version of the question.  It should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: MartyFouts, I assumed as much but did not know how to check. Thank you @Nathan for confirming!

Comment: The way to check that always works:  After you try to parent with automatic weights, and before you do anything else, open the Info Window and look at the last few messages.  The failure message will be there.